# Combine row data into list type for a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

my dataframe looks like -

```
WIT_ID      ML_ENTITY_TYPE  ML_ENTITY_NAME   EDT_ENTITY_NAME    USER_ACTION IS_MAIN 
17668620    RBNAME          MANGO            NaN                3           0   
17668620    RBNAME          BANANA           NaN                3           0   
17668620    DRWECNTRY       SINGAPORE        NaN                3           0   
17668620    TRNSPVESSEL     DUMMY            NaN                3           0
```

I want to combine the `ML_ENTITY_NAME`  in list type for same `WIT_ID` ans same `ML_ENTITY_TYPE` also, `EDT_ENTITY_NAME    USER_ACTION IS_MAIN` would remain same allthroughout the dataframe.

```
WIT_ID      ML_ENTITY_TYPE  ML_ENTITY_NAME   EDT_ENTITY_NAME    USER_ACTION IS_MAIN 
17668620    RBNAME          [MANGO,BANANA]   NaN                3           0   
17668620    DRWECNTRY       SINGAPORE        NaN                3           0   
17668620    TRNSPVESSEL     DUMMY            NaN                3           0
```

currently my approach is something that looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275765/pandas-merge-row-data-with-multiple-values-to-python-list-for-a-column)

but I'm unable to apply that solution correctly for my dataframe.

If some one has any suggestions, answers or need any more information regarding this query then please comment/answer.

Comment: `but I'm unable to apply that solution correctly for my dataframe.` - Can you explain more? What is your code what not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40432845/new-column-in-pandas-adding-series-to-dataframe-by-applying-a-list-groupby) link that might be helpful. Basically the line you might be looking for is

```
df.join(df.groupby(['WIT_ID','ML_ENTITY_TYPE'])['ML_ENTITY_NAME'].apply(list).to_frame('new_column'),on = ['WIT_ID','ML_ENTITY_TYPE'])
```

This adds a new column with the combined values of 'ML_ENTITY_TYPE'.

Answer (score 0):

There should be problem if grouping by column(s) with `NaN`s then all groups are excluded. Solution is replace `NaN` by temporay value, apply solution and replace back:

Solution if grouping by all columns without `ML_ENTITY_NAME`:

```
df1 = (df.fillna('MISS')
       .groupby(df.columns.difference(['ML_ENTITY_NAME']).tolist())['ML_ENTITY_NAME']
       .agg(list)
       .reset_index()
       .reindex(columns=df.columns)
       .replace('MISS', np.nan))
print (df1)

     WIT_ID ML_ENTITY_TYPE   ML_ENTITY_NAME  EDT_ENTITY_NAME  USER_ACTION  \
0  17668620      DRWECNTRY      [SINGAPORE]              NaN            3   
1  17668620         RBNAME  [MANGO, BANANA]              NaN            3   
2  17668620    TRNSPVESSEL          [DUMMY]              NaN            3   

   IS_MAIN  
0        0  
1        0  
2        0
```