# Python,Pandas,DataFrame, add new column doing SQL GROUP_CONCAT equivalent

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My question is very similar to the one asked but unanswered here
[Replicating GROUP_CONCAT for pandas.DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138693/replicating-group-concat-for-pandas-dataframe)

I have a Pandas DataFame which I want to group concat into a data frame

```
+------+---------+  
| team | user    |  
+------+---------+  
| A    | elmer   |  
| A    | daffy   |  
| A    | bugs    |  
| B    | dawg    |  
| A    | foghorn |  
+------+---------+
```

Becoming

```
+------+---------------------------------------+  
| team | group_concat(user)                    |  
+------+---------------------------------------+  
| A    | elmer,daffy,bugs,foghorn              |  
| B    | dawg                                  | 
+------+---------------------------------------+
```

As answeed in the original topic, it can be done via any of these:

```
df.groupby('team').apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.user))
df.groupby('team').apply(lambda x: list(x.user))
df.groupby('team').agg({'user' : lambda x: ', '.join(x)})
```

But the resulting object is not a `Pandas` `Dataframe` anymore.
How can I get the GROUP_CONCAT results in the original `Pandas` `DataFrame` as a new column?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the below code:

- Firstly, `groupby` **team** and, use `apply` on the **user** to `join` it's elements using a `,`
- Then, reset the index, and `rename` the resulting dataframe (`axis=1`, refers to columns and not rows)

```
res = (df.groupby('team')['user']
       .apply(lambda x: ','.join(str(i) for i in x))).reset_index().rename({'user':'group_concat(user)'},axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  team        group_concat(user)
0    A  elmer,daffy,bugs,foghorn
1    B                      dawg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `list` and `join` after grouping by, then reset_index to get the dataframe.

```
output_df = df.groupby('team')['user'].apply(lambda x: ",".join(list(x))).reset_index()
output_df.rename(columns={'user': 'group_concat(user)'})

    team    group_concat(user)
0   A   elmer,daffy,bugs,foghorn
1   B   dawg
```